# Estimate assignment probabilities of a multi-class classification problem

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, classification, supervised-learning

I a dataset of $N$ observations $x_1, \ldots, x_N$. We know that to each observation $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^k$ one of $m$ possible class labels has been assigned to it $y_i\in\{1, \ldots, m\}$.

For each observation, I would like to estimate a vector of probabilities $p_i\in (0, 1)^m$ where the $j^{\text{th}}$ entry gives the probability that $x_i$ got assigned class $y_i$.

> What is this problem called and what are some possible strategies to solve it?

Note that this is slightly different from multi-class classification since my aim is not to classify but to figure out assignment probabilities.

Comment: The question isn’t very clear, you are just looking for the probabilities of belonging to each class? Most algorithms do this, if not by giving actual probabilities (logistic regression) by giving what could be seen as pseudo-probabilities (random forest). It doesn’t have a specific name other than classification

Comment: Exactly. Basically I want to find the probabilities of belonging to each class, but I don't care too much about classification accuracy. You are right multinomial logistic regression allows you to get these probabilities.

Comment: Then there isn’t any question really. As I said most algorithms will output some form of a probability. If you aren’t interested in classification accuracy just stop at the probabilities